# How to Specify Storing Path in AWS Amplify in Android.?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm able to store files with the AWS Amplify Storage category. However, they all are being stored in the top of the public folder in my bucket. How do I specify a path inside the public folder?

I referenced both the [JavaScript](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage) and [Android](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/storage) documentation for Amplify storage.

Here's my code.

```java
Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
    "filenmae.txt",
    filename.getAbsolutePath(),
    new ResultListener<StorageUploadFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(StorageUploadFileResult result) {
            Log.i("StorageQuickStart", "Successfully uploaded: " + result.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.e("StorageQuickstart", "Upload error.", error);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi welcome, please have a quick tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: please provide the code of your implementation and what have you tried so far

Comment: @AshwiniViolet Thanks fro replay.Could you please  my question now.I have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload A file to a specific folder, then all you have to do is add the folder name path prefix to your 1st key parameter of the method `Amplify.Storage.uploadFile()`.

**For Example**

let's say you want to upload your files in a folder that have name "game".

```java
// Name of your folder with '/' in the end to make it like path prefix
String folderGame = "game/";

// here we just adding it before the name of your file 
String key = folderGame +"filenmae.txt";            

/*
 * Now the value in key will look like "game/filenmae.txt" and 
 * pass it in method as first parameter where you were passing 
 * the name previously.
 */
Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
    key,
    filename.getAbsolutePath(),
    new ResultListener<StorageUploadFileResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(StorageUploadFileResult result) {
            Log.i("StorageQuickStart", "Successfully uploaded: " + result.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.e("StorageQuickstart", "Upload error.", error);
        }
    }
);
```

**Extra**

For the other methods like download, remove etc., you have to do the same thing to access these files. Just add the prefix.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Working Perfectly.